# Getting rid of duplicate elements based on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, duplicates

I know this question has been raised prior but unable to get any of the previously provided solutions to work on my XML.

My XML document is as follows. My requirement is to generate a simple html table for each "Product" element and their respective "pa:RepaymentFrequency" and "pa:RepaymentType" elements.

The "pa:RepaymentFrequency" and "pa:RepaymentType" elements are duplicated within each "Product" element and my requirement is to get rid off the duplicates of the "pa:RepaymentFrequency" and "pa:RepaymentType". Note that the "pa:RepaymentFrequency" and "pa:RepaymentType" are determined based on their attribute node "value". I am using XSLT 1.0 for your information.

For example

```
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Weekly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Fortnightly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Monthly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Monthly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Weekly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
```

once got rid off the duplicates

```
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Weekly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Fortnightly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
<pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Monthly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
```

Same should be with  .

(1) I have tried grouping with "Muenchian" as follows.

```
<xsl:template-match="Product">
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:for-each select=".//pa:RepaymentFrequency[generate-id() 
    = generate-id(key('product-group', @value)[1]]">
    <xsl:value-of-select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </td>
 </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

(2) Have also tried the below

```
<xsl:template match="Product">
<tr>
<xsl:variable name="distinct_values" select=".//pa:RepaymentFrequency/@value[not(preceding::pa:RepaymentFrequency/@value = .)]"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$distinct_values">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:apply-templates/>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
```

On both occasions it will work for the first  element encountered in the XML document and will not work for the rest (both approaches outputting the same XML).

Any help on this is much appreciated.

My XML is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <OldProducts>
        <Product display="###" productcode="###" productname="###" longname="###">
            <pa:RepaymentType value="###"></pa:RepaymentType>
            <pa:RepaymentType value="###"></pa:RepaymentType>
            <pa:TotalTerm minInclusive="###" maxInclusive="###"></pa:TotalTerm>
            <Class display="###" malid="###" longname="###">
                <pa:FixedTerm value="###"></pa:FixedTerm>
            </Class>
        </Product>
        <Product display="###" productcode="###" productname="###" longname="###">
            <pa:TotalTerm minInclusive="###" maxInclusive="###"></pa:TotalTerm>
            <pa:RepaymentType value="###"></pa:RepaymentType>
            <pa:RepaymentType value="###"></pa:RepaymentType>
            <pa:Feature name="###"></pa:Feature>`enter code here`
            <pa:Feature name="###"></pa:Feature>
        </Product>
    </OldProducts>
    <Products>
        <pa:TotalAmount minInclusive="###"></pa:TotalAmount>
        <Product display="###">
            <Product display="###" productcode="###" productname="###" longname="###" discontinued="###" legacy="###">
                <pa:TotalTerm minInclusive="###" maxInclusive="###"></pa:TotalTerm>
                <pa:FixedTerm minInclusive="###" maxInclusive="###"></pa:FixedTerm>
                <pa:Amount minInclusive="###"></pa:Amount>
                <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Weekly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Fortnightly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Monthly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                <Class display="###" productcode="###" malid="###" longname="###" PMPID="###" discontinued="###" legacy="###">
                    <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Test-RepaymentFrequencyB"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                    <pa:FixedTerm value="###"></pa:FixedTerm>
                    <pa:Feature name="###"></pa:Feature>
                    <pa:LoanFeature value="###"></pa:LoanFeature>
                    <pa:RepaymentType value="###">
                        <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Test-RepaymentFrequencyB"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                        <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                        <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                        <!-- Added to disable restrictions during testing -->
                        <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                    </pa:RepaymentType>
                </Class>
            </Product>
            <Product display="###" productcode="###" productname="###" longname="###" malid="###" PMPID="###" value="###" discontinued="###" legacy="###">
                <pa:TotalTerm minInclusive="###" maxInclusive="###"></pa:TotalTerm>
                <pa:Amount minInclusive="###"></pa:Amount>
                <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Monthly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                <pa:RepaymentType value="###">
                    <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Weekly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                    <pa:RepaymentFrequency value="Fortnightly"></pa:RepaymentFrequency>
                    <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                    <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                    <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                </pa:RepaymentType>
                <pa:RepaymentType value="###">
                    <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                    <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                    <!-- Added to disable restrictions during testing -->
                    <pa:RepaymentMethod value="###"></pa:RepaymentMethod>
                </pa:RepaymentType>
                <pa:IOTerm minInclusive="###" maxInclusive="###"></pa:IOTerm>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</Data>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the actual output you expect in this case? Thank you!

Comment: To perform Muenchian grouping within a parent element, you must include the parent's unique id in the key. There are many examples of this posted here, see one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926802/xslt-1-0-nested-grouping/43927218#43927218