# nested grouping in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, nested, grouping

Before i go to the actual question i must say certain things. i understand  this topic is already discussed much in this forum. but still my situation is bit unique.

i have to perform this transform inside a tool called **BMC atrium orchestrator version 7.9** , which uses not just xslt 1.0 but the XSLT processor it uses is also bit older or not that much friendly .why am saying this at the very begging is

[xslt 1.0 nested grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926802/xslt-1-0-nested-grouping)

this very simple nested transform listed above in the link itself , am not able to perform in that tool . just copying and pasting the source xml and xslt it showing error.

**below is the source xml**

```
 <root>
    <order>
        <item>
            <item_type>A</item_type>
            <item_type>A</item_type>
            <item_type>B</item_type>
            <item_type>C</item_type>
        </item>
    </order>
    <order>
        <item>
            <item_type>A</item_type>
            <item_type>B</item_type>
            <item_type>C</item_type>
            <item_type>C</item_type>
        </item>
    </order>
    <order>
        <item>
            <item_type>C</item_type>
            <item_type>C</item_type>
            <item_type>B</item_type>
        </item>
    </order>
 </root>
```

**below is the source xslt**

```
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="groups" match="item_type" use="concat(., '|', generate-id(ancestor::order))"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="order">
            <order>                
                <xsl:for-each select="item/item_type[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', concat(., '|', generate-id(ancestor::order)))[1])]">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>     
            </order>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***above xml & XSLT is  solely given to say that such a simple transformation is not working for some reason with my tool. screen shots in comment section. but that is not my actual problem. as i gave the  background  , now am moving to actual question***

**my source xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <element>
      <credat>20180518</credat>
      <cretim>06:25:10</cretim>
      <docnum>1177016</docnum>
      <emailidCc>VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM;RAJNISH.SINHA@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-039723</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-150.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-PK</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-GB20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-GB30</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-A012A02</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; &amp; : Original Batch &amp; differs from Confirmed Batch &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180518</credat>
      <cretim>06:26:30</cretim>
      <docnum>1177017</docnum>
      <emailidCc>VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM;RAJNISH.SINHA@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-039723</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-150.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-PK</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-GB20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-GB30</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-A012A02</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; &amp; : Original Batch &amp; differs from Confirmed Batch &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180518</credat>
      <cretim>06:26:51</cretim>
      <docnum>1177018</docnum>
      <emailidCc>VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM;RAJNISH.SINHA@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-039723</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-150.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-PK</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-GB20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-GB30</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-A012A02</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; &amp; : Original Batch &amp; differs from Confirmed Batch &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180604</credat>
      <cretim>12:21:35</cretim>
      <docnum>1177592</docnum>
      <emailidCc>VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM;RAJNISH.SINHA@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-039723</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-150.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-PK</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-GB20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-GB30</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-A012A02</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; &amp; : Original Batch &amp; differs from Confirmed Batch &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180604</credat>
      <cretim>12:21:45</cretim>
      <docnum>1177593</docnum>
      <emailidCc>VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM;RAJNISH.SINHA@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-039723</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-150.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-PK</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-GB20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-GB30</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-A012A02</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; &amp; : Original Batch &amp; differs from Confirmed Batch &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180614</credat>
      <cretim>16:04:13</cretim>
      <docnum>1178094</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180618</credat>
      <cretim>12:07:05</cretim>
      <docnum>1178407</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180619</credat>
      <cretim>09:08:31</cretim>
      <docnum>1178456</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180619</credat>
      <cretim>09:12:07</cretim>
      <docnum>1178644</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180619</credat>
      <cretim>10:13:17</cretim>
      <docnum>1178649</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>15:25:03</cretim>
      <docnum>1178722</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>15:27:48</cretim>
      <docnum>1178723</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>15:31:47</cretim>
      <docnum>1178724</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>15:35:49</cretim>
      <docnum>1178725</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>15:38:50</cretim>
      <docnum>1178726</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>15:42:36</cretim>
      <docnum>1178727</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>15:44:40</cretim>
      <docnum>1178728</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180620</credat>
      <cretim>16:01:54</cretim>
      <docnum>1178732</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT121</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180621</credat>
      <cretim>08:21:13</cretim>
      <docnum>1178745</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT121</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180628</credat>
      <cretim>10:17:25</cretim>
      <docnum>1180138</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCR</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT121</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>&amp; exceeded by &amp; &amp; &amp;</statusMessage>
   </element>
   <element>
      <credat>20180628</credat>
      <cretim>10:19:32</cretim>
      <docnum>1180139</docnum>
      <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@MERCK.COM</emailidCc>
      <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM</emailidTo>
      <field1>MATERIAL-111116</field1>
      <field14>ENTRY_QNT-20.000</field14>
      <field15>ENTRY_UOM-EA</field15>
      <field2>PLANT-RU20</field2>
      <field3>STGE_LOC-RU20</field3>
      <field4>BATCH-E979A01</field4>
      <field5>MOVE_TYPE-101</field5>
      <idocStatus>Business Input Needed</idocStatus>
      <mestyp>MBGMCL</mestyp>
      <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
      <statusCode>51</statusCode>
      <statusMessage>Posting only possible in periods &amp;1 and &amp;2 in company code &amp;3</statusMessage>
   </element>
</root>
```

my desired result :

```
        <root>
           <element>
              <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
              <mestype>MBGMCR</mestype>
              <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@xx.COM</emailidCc>       <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@MERCK.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@xx.COM</emailidTo>
                <docnum>
                    1177016
                    1177017
                    1177018
                    1177592
                    1177593
                    1178094
                    1178407
                    1178456
                    1178644
                    1178649
                    1178722
                    1178723
                    1178724
                    1178725
                    1178726
                    1178727
                    1178728
                  </docnum>
       </element>

        <element>
        <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@xx.COM</emailidCc>                                                                        
   <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@xxx.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@xx.COM</emailidTo>
        <rcvprn>SR1CLNT121</rcvprn>
        <mestype>MBGMCR</mestype>
                <docnum>
                    1178732
                    1178745
                    1180138
              </docnum>
        </element>


       <element>
        <emailidCc>RAJASHEKAR.ALETI@xx.COM</emailidCc>
 <emailidTo>SREENIVAS.K@xxx.COM;VIJAYMAHANTESH.PAWADI1@xx.COM</emailidTo>
        <rcvprn>SR1CLNT120</rcvprn>
        <mestype>MBGMCL</mestype>
                <docnum>
                     1180139
              </docnum>
        </element>
        </root>
```

**Now i will say the grouping rules :**

1. docnum is the element to be grouped
2. all docnum elements having same rcvprn and msgtyp values must be            grouped in to one  and their email
   id "to" and "cc" must be Unioned respectively with each other  .

**future requirement**
in future there may be couple of other feilds might get added to club the docnum feilds.

Comment: Well, if you get an error then at least tell us exactly which error you get.

Comment: It might also help knowing which XSLT processor your tool uses. Although if it is not XSLT 1.0 conformant there's not much we can do to help, since we don't know which standard it does conform to.

Comment: https://ibb.co/hR1LC1y
in the above link right hand side u can see the error. left hand side you can see the options available in  the builtin tool to build an xslt

Comment: The screenshot and the error message suggest you are trying to use XSLT 2.0 `for-each-group` with an XSLT 1 processor so no idea why you link to an XSLT 1.0 article about nested grouping and claim it doesn't work, I don't see any `for-each-group` in the older post you linked to.

Comment: https://ibb.co/5vVHLCQ   -> please refer this sir. that was a wrong screen shot i uploaded. i applogies for that.  this is a screen shot of a valid xslt 1 grouping. this is what not working . 
xml and xslt used are from the same above article i quoted.

Comment: Can you please copy the actual XSLT into your question, rather than show a screen shot? (Or, if too big, create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that also exhibits the same issue). Thank you!

Comment: sure will do in another 10 mins

Comment: @TimC  actually am not sure which xslt you are refering to . the screen shot thing was totaly done to show the capablity of  my xslt processor ( that its not doing a simple grouping transform using XSl:key element). but my actuall problem  i have already given the source xml and desired xml. 

i have  tried some transforms  for 5 days but nothing is working. rather i dont know how to do.

**  i recently confomred with the product team that  the tool i use supports xslt v1.0 . so if i can get some transform which works in any XSLT1.0  processor should work in my tool as well **

Comment: I am referring to the XSLT that is getting there error. There is a small chance the error message is totally misleading, and that there is actually an issue elsewhere in the XSLT document. Thank you!

Comment: done . i have  given the example xml and corresponding transformation which did not  work well in my tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your XSLT, so your XSLT processor must be really old if it does not support `xsl:key`. (Or possibly, it does not like `concat` or `generate-id`. You could try defining the key as `<xsl:key name="groups" match="item_type" use="."/>`, for example. Although that would be no good for getting your output, it may help narrow down the problem with the processor)

If `xsl:key` is indeed not supported, you would have to fall back to the inefficient way of doing things, and simply check preceding siblings

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="order">
            <order>                
                <xsl:for-each select="item/item_type[not(. = preceding-sibling::item_type)]">
                    <item>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>     
            </order>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: To put this sample to practise, for your actual XML, it becomes much nastier, but try this (very inefficient) XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/element[not(rcvprn = preceding-sibling::element/rcvprn)]">
      <xsl:variable name="rcvprn" select="rcvprn" />
      <xsl:variable name="rvcprngroup" select="../element[rcvprn = $rcvprn]" />

      <xsl:for-each select="$rvcprngroup[not(mestyp = preceding-sibling::element[rcvprn = $rcvprn]/mestyp)]">
        <xsl:variable name="mestyp" select="mestyp" />
        <xsl:variable name="mestypgroup" select="$rvcprngroup[mestyp = $mestyp]" />

        <element>
          <xsl:copy-of select="mestyp|rcvprn"/>
          <emailidTo>
            <xsl:for-each select="$mestypgroup">
              <xsl:value-of select="emailidTo" />
              <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </emailidTo>
          <docnum>
            <xsl:for-each select="$mestypgroup[not(docnum = preceding-sibling::element[rcvprn = $rcvprn and mestyp = $mestyp]/docnum)]">
              <xsl:value-of select="docnum" />
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </docnum>
        </element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>     
  </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **this worked**. it seems the processor is really old as you said. that answers the problem with my processor. but can u please help me in my actual problem. 
below is one of the statement i have really worked on yesterday to filter out unique **rcvprn** element. 
`/root/element[not(rcvprn=preceding-sibling::element/rcvprn)]/rcvprn`  but 

am not sure how to go further and group the docnum . because there is one more filtration req from the first filter . ie to filter based on **msgtype**  . and then to  merge/unionise the distinct **emailto** and **emailcc**. am just 6 months old to XSLT!

Comment: Ah! This is going to be troublesome. I've made an edit to my answer, to show the rather nasty XSLT. I now need to go have a lie-down.....

Comment: worked like charm ! i learned a lot from this . thanks for it .  there is one small left out. those email ids should not be concatinated directly. it should be clubbed. as in , if there are two email ids only one should come. i mean only distinct values. i am working on that part. i will update that.

Comment: seems outlook / Mic-Exchange will filter out the duplicate mail ids ! so as of now no issues. but still it would be great if duplicate email ids could be filtered using any XSLT 1.0 function